# How to call a class from a project to another project without call the DLL as reference in C#?

Tags: c#, dll, reference

I have three parts of a project, one is Core(bussiness) project, one is webproject and the last is the test project.

I want to call some classes that I saved in one folder from core project to webproject without calling the dll of the core project. Since core project is already refereed into the webproject. So it will call the cycling if the references and not allow me to do that.

How I can use classes from core project to web project without call the DLL?
I Have already tried 'using', The code is following. It's not working for me.

```
using BlogEngine.Core.API.PageML; // I need to call all classes from this folder
using BlogPage = BlogEngine.Core.API.PageML;
namespace admin.Settings
{
 public partial class DownloadInsertPage : System.Web.UI.Page{
  protected void BtnPageMLInsertClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   var reader = new PageReaders(); // the class, I want to call from the core project
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: "Since web project is already refereed into the webproject" uncleared

Answer (score 3):

Your question is unclear ("since web project is already refereed into the webproject" for example) but you should really make the web project have a reference to the core project, but *not* the other way round. The core business logic shouldn't know about your web "view" onto it, but the web project should absolutely know about the core business classes.

If you have classes in the web project which you're currently referring to from the core project, you should probably move them to the core project - or to a third project which both of the other projects refer to, if they don't logically belong in the core project itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your model may benefit from contract interfaces - that would help you redesign your current model in order to avoid circular references. Here's some posts about this:

[a design to avoid circular reference in this scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724989/a-design-to-avoid-circular-reference-in-this-scenario)

[Resolving Circular References (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320561/resolving-circular-references-c?rq=1)

Now, I may have misunderstood your question, and you'd rather benefit more from learning about add-on models. In that case, this post may be of some help:

[C# Plugin Architecture with interfaces share between plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829597/c-sharp-plugin-architecture-with-interfaces-share-between-plugins)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

If you need these classes to be accessible in both assembly, you should create a third one that would be referenced by both of them although this should be reserved to cross-cutting concerns only (e.g. logging logic).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your valuable comments.. 
I want to share, what was the problem and how I resolved it.

I build the core project after created some classes into the PageML folder and build it without calling this folder into the web project. and update the reference(dll) of core project in the webproject. and it's working for me.

Thank you All

Keep clam and do coding.

:) have a nice time